# PDF -Adobe Digital Edition

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

I would like to protect a pdf document using Adobe Digital Edition. I think that it is currently being used to protect the eBooks to prevent illegal circulation.

Can any one throw some light on that. Is it possible to do it using C# or something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Adobe Content Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/contentserver/) and the [Adobe Digital Publishing Technology Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/digitalpublishing/) websites for some direction.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use C#: [See SDK Info Doc](http://web.archive.org/web/20100604014756/http://www.adobe.com/devnet/digitalpublishing/pdfs/ADE_LauncherSDK_DevNet.pdf).  You can use any server side processing language.

Comment: Eight years later, this gives a 404. The document is currently here: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/digitalpublishing/pdfs/ADE_LauncherSDK_DevNet.pdf

Comment: @Bas, this link also gives 404 now.

Comment: Archive of original link: http://web.archive.org/web/20100604014756/http://www.adobe.com/devnet/digitalpublishing/pdfs/ADE_LauncherSDK_DevNet.pdf