# Access adobe digital editions from the command line

Tags: command-line, adobe

I'm looking to create a script for my 80-year old grandmother that downloads the books she needs, and converts them using the command-line version of Calibre, to kindle format so she can read them on her kindle. She gets a lot of her books from a service in the form of Adobe .epub books. AFAIK, none of these books have DRM on them prior to being converted, so let me be clear - I'm not asking how to strip DRM from an ebook.

What I *am* asking is whether there is a way to programmatically (from the command line is fine if Adobe Digital Editions supports CL args) use the ticket file to request a book from the library, and download it, in .epub form, to the local hard drive. I simply don't want my grandmother to have to go through all of the unneeded screens in Adobe Digital Editions' interface - she gets confused easily, and the interface tends to be overwhelming for her. I simply want to write a function (it can be a system() call to a command... that's fine) that will allow her to take a file received from the library or digital service and automatically retrieve the proper .epub file.

I have all of the other steps ready to go... I just can't find any way to retrieve the book from the service without using the DE interface.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531901/pdf-adobe-digital-edition

Comment: Actually, yes, that did help now that I re-read it. If you post as an answer, I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your solution? I'm trying the same thing, but I do not understand how to use this SDK on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this S.O. posting, I know it will help ;-)

[pdf-adobe-digital-edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531901/pdf-adobe-digital-edition)

Comment: Thanks. Coincidentally, I did read that post prior to posting, but for some reason glossed over the fact that a link to an SDK was provided. Heh. Thanks for the re-point in the right direction, though.