# How to get the epub from an acsm file?

Tags: adobe, epub, drm

I want to write a small linux tool that automates the download of eBooks. From my online library I can download an ACSM file. Now I need a step to **automatically** download the epub file. From what I've read this step is called fulfilment. The tool shall run on a headless server.

Right now I'm scripting wine and Adobe Digital Editions. But that is quite ugly and requires a graphical user interface. While this works fine on my PC, it doesn't work on a headless server.

Does anyone know a library that I could use?
Or a documentation of the fulfilment process so I could implement my own library?

In "[PDF -Adobe Digital Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531901/pdf-adobe-digital-edition)" I saw a reference to the ADE_LauncherSDK_DevNet.pdf but I do not understand how to use this in an application.

Notes:

- I do **not** want to remove the DRM, I just want to get the epub file.
- The tool will be open source, so I do not want to buy anything from Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a 9 years old question but because I ended up on it with the exact same question, I wanted to give an answer.

Indeed, the code to download an epub/pdf from an acsm file can be found in 2 projects.

> **libgourou** is a free implementation of Adobe's ADEPT protocol used to
> add DRM on ePub/PDF files. It overcome the lacks of Adobe support for
> Linux platforms.

https://indefero.soutade.fr//p/libgourou/

There is a docker version: https://github.com/bcliang/docker-libgourou/

> **Calibre ACSM Input plugin**
>
> This is a Calibre plugin that allows you to
> turn ACSM files into EPUB or PDF files without the need for Adobe
> Digital Editions. It is a full Python reimplementation of libgourou by
> Grégory Soutadé (http://indefero.soutade.fr/p/libgourou/), and has
> since been extended by more and more features.

https://github.com/Leseratte10/acsm-calibre-plugin

Calibre has a command line interface: https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/cli-index.html